# Proper use of viewDidUnload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, viewdidunload

I know that similar questions have been asked before. But I've been searching SO for some time now and things are still a bit confusing. So here goes...

I am not using ARC.
If you have a viewcontroller with an instance variable and a property like below:

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    NSDictionary *someDict;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *someView;
@property(assign)UIView *someOtherView;
```

ViewController.m:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload{
    self.someView = nil;
    [someDict release];
    [someOtherView release];
    super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement viewDidUnload?
Setting someDict = nil seems wrong as it will leak hence my guess is release. 
The same applies to someOtherView as it is not retained?

Am I wrong here? Thankful for any help!

Comment: I believe if you are using ARC then you just use `someDict = nil;`

Comment: I am not using ARC... hence the edit

Comment: nice question, i believe this question is the 1st question asked by new iOS programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.someView = nil` will not leak since it equals to `[self setSomeView:nil]` which is generated automatically by property-synthesize pair of `@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *someView`. It has `retain` attribute so the retained object will be released when a new object is set.

I believe `[someDict release];` should be in `dealloc`. And `[someOtherView release];` shouldn't be called since it is an `assign` property which doesn't have ownership.

More references:

- [When should I release objects in -(void)viewDidUnload rather than in -dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158788/when-should-i-release-objects-in-voidviewdidunload-rather-than-in-dealloc)
- [Deallocation when iPhone is turned back on from sleep and app is still open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676603/deallocation-when-iphone-is-turned-back-on-from-sleep-and-app-is-still-open)

Comment: Thanks for answering! The first one i was quite sure about, but the other two? Any leads?

Comment: `someDict` is a member of your class, it shouldn't be released until the instance will be destroyed. `viewDidUnload` is not the correct place. For `someOtherView`, it looks like a weak reference to another view, that's the reason I said that.

Comment: More references added in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidUnload` you should release and nil all views that are retained subviews of your view controller's main view (i.e. not dictionaries!). It's that simple.

So your

```
self.someView = nil;
```

is correct, just add all your other retained subviews in to the method as well.

Don't release `someOtherView`, as this is an assigned property. Releasing it will cause your app to crash.

And if I were you, I'd get rid of the iVar declarations (`someDict`), and use all properties.

Comment: so you mean that if the dictionary someDict was a view it should have been released as it was not a retained property? and the same for the someOtherView?

Comment: I took your advice on getting rid of all ivars, but that raises a question. What about inheritance?